# Linker Flag/Boost not found -- linking Boost filesystem with Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, boost, boost-filesystem

I am trying to the use Boost Filesystem library in Xcode.

I installed Boost with `brew install boost`, and it was successful.

Turns out Boost wasn't linked so I ran `brew link --overwrite Boost`, which worked.

I am trying to `#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>` in my project, but have not been successful so far.

At first Xcode couldn't find `<boost/filesystem.hpp>`, so I added

```
/usr/local/lib
/usr/local/include
```

to my Header search paths for Target and Project.

That fixed the original problem, but then boost_system could not be found by Xcode.
Here is the transcript:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::system::system_category()", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init2 in main.o
  "boost::system::generic_category()", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init in main.o
      ___cxx_global_var_init1 in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I added the -lboost_system linker flag to my project, and now I am getting this error:

```
ld: library not found for -lboost_system
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

And it's definitely the correct linker flag, so perhaps Boost installed incorrectly after all.
I will update this question if I find a solution, but I would appreciate help in solving this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need `/usr/local/include` in your *header search path* and you need `/usr/local/lib` in your *library search path* in order for the linker to find the libraries.

Comment: The header search path tells the compiler where to find non-standard include files and the library search path tells the linker where to find non-standard libraries.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem in xcode 6 . user header search path and library search was okay . still showed link error . I solved the problem by adding `-lboost_system-mt` in other linker flag in project target  setting